# Data Structure with insert , delete of complexity of O(log n) & successor, predecessor of O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is there any data structure, other than binary tree, that can do the following:

- Insert - O(log n)
- Delete - O(log n)
- Find - O(log n)
- Successor - O(1)
- Predecessor - O(1)

A doubly linked list falls short on the find complexity.
A simple sorted indexed array falls short on the insert\delete complexity.

Thanks!

Comment: B-tree family... especially B+tree.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Comment: (Not the branching factor limits tree operation times - *balance* does.)

Comment: Is the question theoretical, or do you have a real problem to solve?

Comment: Furthermore, what's wrong with a tree?